# How can I override windowDidLoad method in a custom class in order get notified my window did load?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

All I am trying in this question is about get notified when window itself did load, in order to try solve the issue i make a sub class of `NSWindowController` and named it as `MyNSWindowController` and put my needed code for solving the issue, but Xcode make an error of:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSWindowController' to specified type 'MyNSWindowController'

Here is my codes:

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    private var window: NSWindow!
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        
        buildMainMenu()
        
        buildWindow()
        
    }
    
    func buildWindow() {
        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.title = "No Storyboard Window"
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
        window.center()
    }
    
    func buildMainMenu() {
        
        let appMainMenu: NSMenu = NSMenu()
        
        let mainMenu: NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
        mainMenu.submenu = NSMenu(title: "MainMenu")
        
        let mainMenuItem0 = NSMenuItem(title: "About", action: #selector(NSApplication.about), keyEquivalent: "a")
        mainMenuItem0.keyEquivalentModifierMask = .command
        
        let mainMenuItem1 = NSMenuItem(title: "Close", action: #selector(NSWindow.performClose(_:)), keyEquivalent: "w")
        mainMenuItem1.keyEquivalentModifierMask = .command
        
        let mainMenuItem2 = NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(NSApplication.shared.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q")
        mainMenuItem2.keyEquivalentModifierMask = .command
        
        mainMenu.submenu?.items = [mainMenuItem0, mainMenuItem1, mainMenuItem2]
        appMainMenu.items = [mainMenu]
        
        NSApp.mainMenu = appMainMenu
        
    }
    
}


extension NSApplication {
    @objc func about() {
        AboutView().openInWindow(title: "About My App", sender: self)
    }
}

struct AboutView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.green
            .frame(width: 500, height: 200)
    }
}


extension View {
    
    @discardableResult
    func openInWindow(title: String, sender: Any?) -> NSWindow {

        let window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500.0, height: 500.0),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        
        // let myNSWindowController: NSWindowController = NSWindowController(window: window)
        let myNSWindowController: MyNSWindowController = NSWindowController(window: window)
        
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
        window.center()
        window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.title = "No Storyboard Window"
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: self)
 
        return window
    }
}


class MyNSWindowController: NSWindowController {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
         print("Window did load!")
    }
    
}
```

If you think my plan is not good about get notified when window get load, you can come with better answer for solving the issue and goal, I have to say I am trying to find a native way in Cocoa to work as `.onAppear` modifier which we have in SwiftUI. In SwiftUI `.onAppear` modifier is for content of view, here in this question i just want to know when the window did load or appear, just the window itself not what carry this window.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowcontroller) on how to properly sub class NSWindowController but maybe this is better handled using NSViewController

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: Yes, I am not trying solve the issue just with `NSWindowController` which one is better and fit better, I would chose that way.

Comment: Do you load a window (from a nib or storyboard)? Otherwise `windowDidLoad` won't work.

Comment: @Willeke: No, That is all my codes in question, no storyboard or nib, I am using a main file for running the app.

Comment: Just did a quick test, `windowDidLoad` is not called if you don't load the window.